# Android Webview: possible to set usesCleartextTraffic = true only for one single webview and not for all?

Tags: android, security, webview

My application includes a QRcode reader enabling browsing in a webview the URL encoded in the QRcode. However, encoded URLs can be indifferently HTTP or HTTPS and I am not able to browse HTTP websites because, for security reasons, I have to keep the option `"usesCleartextTraffic=false"` in my Manifest.
The option of using NetworkSecurityConfig is not viable, as HTTP websites are not restricted in a domain, but can be everywhere.

Is there a way to enable cleartexttraffic only on a certain webview, in order to reduce security risks?

Or, alternatively, is there any other option to keep the above mentioned flag to false, and, for instance, enabling cleartext traffic only upon certain events (for instance, after a QRCode has been read) ? Can NetworkSecurityConfig be used for such purposes?

Comment: You can enable clear text traffic per domain, in the same configuration from the answer below. Just permit clear text traffic to the domains loaded in the web view.

Comment: See example here - https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted